# Variable "form" does not exist when overriding Symfony2 form theme

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am having an issue all of the sudden where I am getting the following error on my Symfony2 site:
`Variable "form" does not exist in SiteBackendBundle::layout.html.twig at line 2`.

My SiteBackendBundle::layout.html.twig file looks like:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'SiteBackendBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
....
{% endblock %}
```

and my SiteBackendBundle:Form:fields.html.twig looks like this:

```
{% block money_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
  {{ block('form_widget_simple') | raw }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

My config.yml for Symfony/forms looks like this:

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: en }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
```

It's also weird because this was working before I ran `php app/console cache:clear`

Why am I unable to extend the form without getting this error?  This exact method is defined at http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template

Comment: Silly question but are you passing a form variable to your view from your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one or more of the twig files that extend your layout do not contain a form then presumably you won't be passing a form variable to them. You can get round this by updating your layout file as follows:

```
{% if form is defined %}
{% form_theme form 'SiteBackendBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue actually. Not sure if this will help but it helped me. In your Controller you have to put in the array like I am doing inside of your return statement.

```
public function PrefixController extends Controller\
{
    if(...){
    }
    return $this->render('BundleName:ControllerPrefix:TwigTemplate.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
```